# How to load custom NLog target from xml config in Xamarin?

Tags: .net, xamarin, configuration, nlog

I have Xamain native application, where NLog is used for logging.
NLog configuration is stored in xml file, which is Embedded Resource.

**Problem:** custom target is not loaded from NLog xml configuration file, however standard NLog targets are loaded fine (console target in example below).

All works fine, if I put exactly same code in .Net Core console app.
What did I miss?

Custom target:

```
[Target("MyCustomTarget")]
public class CustomTargetWithLayout : TargetWithLayout
{
    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var logMessage = this.RenderLogEvent(this.Layout, logEvent);
        //TODO: write rendered message by custom logic
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="console" type="Console" />
    <target name="customTarget" xsi:type="MyCustomTarget" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="customTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Configuration is loaded by following code:

```
var embeddedResourceStream = 
    Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()).GetManifestResourceStream("MyAppNamespace.NLogConfig.xml");

if (embeddedResourceStream != null)
{
    var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(embeddedResourceStream);
    LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(xmlReader, null);
}
// Only console target loaded in LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic extension loading doesn't always work. Maybe you are missing this in NLog.config:

```
  <extensions> 
    <add assembly="MyCustomAssembly"/> 
  </extensions>
```

Maybe try this to prevent the AOT-Linker to remove anything not referenced:

```
[assembly: Preserve(typeof(MyCustomNameSpace.CustomTargetWithLayout), AllMembers = true)]
```

NLog ver. 4.6 includes this assembly-attribute by default (But it only applies to classes in NLog.dll). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3039

Alternative you could manually register the target (before allocating Logger or loading NLog-config):

```
NLog.Target.Register<MyCustomNameSpace.CustomTargetWithLayout>("MyFirst");
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component

Comment: I found answer in link you provided - need to add assembly to extensions in config.
<extensions>
  <add assembly="AssemblyWithMyCustomTarget"/>
</extensions>